# Python 3 how to remove a specific string in a list and to reset it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some sample code right here:

```
test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m']
remove = ['a','m','g']

for a in remove:
    b = test
    b.remove(a)
    print(len(b),len(test))
```

which has the output:

```
12 12
11 11
10 10
```

why does it also get removed from test if I am specifying it to be removed from b? Is there a way to unlink this so I am only removing it from b but not test?

Comment: a and b are pointing to the same list, they're one and the same. Just two different names for the same object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: After the assignment, accessing b is accessing test. You should use a copy instead